# Assets not loaded in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new using Laravel. I'm having problems installing a Laravel project when I try to serve it. The project run well, although it's not loading anything in the public folder. This affects all the scripts or css in the web page.

[image]

[image]

Browser claims error 404 although files already exists.

[image]

I figure it out that the problem is that the public folder it's not included and the router responds with a 404 error for any file located there.

[image]

Anyone have idea of what's going on here and how can I solve it?

Comment: its not all, its responding 200 for some stuff in public ... also whats with the ssl requests  ... do you really have a folder in your public folder named `public` ... you are already serving from the public folder, that is the root of the site

Comment: a snippet of code on how you load it  pretty much help

Comment: @lagbox thank you, you help me to find the solution, files were not located inside another ``public`` folder

Comment: The project was not developed by me, I'm just optimizing it, I need to solve that bad practices.

Comment: Why downvote?..